# Stacked bar plot with bars appearing from top of chart and bottom of chart and converging at center

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am using matplotlib and pandas to plot data relating to materials and their bandgaps, and I would like to display it in a format similar to the image below.

[image: silicon band gap]

My code so far:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
mpl.style.use('seaborn-white')


matls = ["Si", "Ge", "SiC", "GaN"]
VB = pd.DataFrame({'materials': matls, 'value': [-5.1, -4.6, -6.37, -7.57]})
CB = pd.DataFrame({'materials': matls, 'value': [-4.05, -4.0, -3.17, -4.1]})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_ylabel("Potential relative to NHE (V)", color = 'C2' )
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C2')
ax1.set_xlabel("Material")
ax1.bar(CB['materials'], CB['value'], bottom = 2., color = 'blue')


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(-4, 2, 13))
ax1.set_ylim(-4, 2)
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(-8.85, -2.85, 13))
ax2.set_ylim(-8.85, -2.85)
ax2.set_ylabel("Energy Relative to Vacuum (eV)", color = 'C5')
ax2.bar(VB['materials'], VB['value'], bottom = -8., color = 'green')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C5')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

As you can see, the bars are just aligned starting at whatever value the bottom is set to, and they do not actually reflect the real values from the array. The bars should have heights determined by the array, so the green bar for Si should start at -5.1 and cover to the bottom and the blue bar should start at -4.05 and go up to the top of the chart. Both bars are wrong.

EDIT:

If I change the values to match the scale bar being used, I obtain the following result.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
mpl.style.use('seaborn-white')


matls = ["Si", "Ge", "SiC", "GaN"]
VB = pd.DataFrame({'materials': matls, 'value': [-5.1, -4.6, -6.37, -7.57]})
CB = pd.DataFrame({'materials': matls, 'value': [0.8, 0.85, 1.68, 0.75]})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_ylabel("Potential relative to NHE (V)", color = 'C2' )
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C2')
ax1.set_xlabel("Material")
ax1.bar(CB['materials'], CB['value'], bottom = 0., color = 'blue')


ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(-4, 2, 13))
ax1.set_ylim(-4, 2)
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(-8.85, -2.85, 13))
ax2.set_ylim(-8.85, -2.85)
ax2.set_ylabel("Energy Relative to Vacuum (eV)", color = 'C5')
ax2.bar(VB['materials'], VB['value'], bottom = -8., color = 'green')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C5')
plt.show()
```

[image: result2]

Comment: What exactly is incorrect about your current plot? Also, is it the blue bars, the green bars, or both that are wrong?

Comment: The bars should have heights determined by the array, so the green bar for Si should start at -5.1 and cover to the bottom and the blue bar should start at -4.05 and go up to the top of the chart. Both bars are wrong.

Comment: What should be the top value of the blue bars and the bottom value of the green bars?

Comment: top value should be determined by top vertical ylimit for blue and bottom value by bottom vertical y limit for green

Comment: Should work thanks

Comment: Does my solution answer your question? If it does, you can click the gray check next to my solution to accept it. If not, please clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `"value"` column of your data frame represents different things for each of the datasets. For the blue dataset, it represents the bottom point, while for the green dataset, it represents the top point. What we can do is set a top value for the blue bars and a bottom value for the green bars and then compute a height based on those values which gives the desired results.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

plt.close("all")

matls = ["Si", "Ge", "SiC", "GaN"]
VB = pd.DataFrame({"materials": matls, "value": [-5.1, -4.6, -6.37, -7.57]})
CB = pd.DataFrame({"materials": matls, "value": [-4.05, -4.0, -3.17, -4.1]})

VB_bottom = round(np.min(VB.value)-1)
CB_top = round(np.max(CB.value)+1)

VB["heights"] = VB_bottom - VB.value
CB["heights"] = CB_top - CB.value

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_ylabel("Potential relative to NHE (V)", color="blue")
ax1.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="blue")
ax1.set_xlabel("Material")
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel("Energy Relative to Vacuum (eV)", color="green")
ax2.tick_params(axis="y", labelcolor="green")
for ax in [ax1, ax2]:
    ax.set_ylim(VB_bottom, CB_top)

ax1.bar(CB.materials, CB.heights, bottom=CB.value, color="blue")
ax2.bar(VB.materials, VB.heights, bottom=VB.value, color="green")

fig.show()
```

[image]